# Scopes not created from a template cannot have FilterParameters Error

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to build on the "WebSharingAppDemo-SqlProviderEndToEnd" msdn sample application to build out a custom MSF implementation. As part of that I added parameterized filters to the provisioning. I have been referencing http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/sync-framework-provisioning/ for some idea of how to do this. Now that I have that in place, when I re-initialize the "peer1" database and try to provision it initially I now get an error:

> Scopes not created from a template cannot have FilterParameters. 
>   Parameter '@my_param_name' was found on Table '[my_table_name]'. 
>   Please ensure that no FilterParameters are being defined on a scope
>   that is not created from a template.

The only guess I have as to what a "template" is, is the provisioning templates that the Sync Toolkit's tools can work with, but I don't think that applies in the scenario I'm working with.

I have been unable to find anything that would indicate what I should do to fix this. So how can I get past this error but still provision my database with parameterized filters?

The below code is what I'm using to build the filtering into the provisioning (`SqlSyncScopeProvisioning`) object.

```
private void AddFiltersToProvisioning(IEnumerable<TableInfo> tables)
{
    IEnumerable<FilterColumn> filters = this.GetFilterColumnInfo();
    foreach (TableInfo tblInfo in tables)
    {
        this.AddFiltersForTable(tblInfo, filters);
    }
}

private void AddFiltersForTable(TableInfo tblInfo, IEnumerable<FilterColumn> filters)
{
    IEnumerable<FilterColumn> tblFilters;
    tblFilters = filters.Where(x => x.FilterLevelID == tblInfo.FilterLevelID);
    if (tblFilters != null && tblFilters.Count() > 0)
    {
        var tblDef = this.GetTableColumns(tblInfo.TableName);
        StringBuilder filterClause = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (FilterColumn column in tblFilters)
        {
            this.AddColumnFilter(tblDef, column.ColumnName, filterClause);
        }

        this.Provisioning.Tables[tblInfo.TableName].FilterClause = filterClause.ToString();
    }
}

private void AddColumnFilter(IEnumerable<TableColumnInfo> tblDef, string columnName, StringBuilder filterClause)
{
    TableColumnInfo columnInfo;
    columnInfo = tblDef.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (columnInfo != null)
    {
        this.FlagColumnForFiltering(columnInfo.TableName, columnInfo.ColumnName);
        this.BuildFilterClause(filterClause, columnInfo.ColumnName);
        this.AddParamter(columnInfo);
    }
}

private void FlagColumnForFiltering(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    this.Provisioning.Tables[tableName].AddFilterColumn(columnName);
}

private void BuildFilterClause(StringBuilder filterClause, string columnName)
{
    if (filterClause.Length > 0)
    {
        filterClause.Append(" AND ");
    }

    filterClause.AppendFormat("[base].[{0}] = @{0}", columnName);
}

private void AddParamter(TableColumnInfo columnInfo)
{
    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@" + columnInfo.ColumnName, columnInfo.GetSqlDataType());
    if (columnInfo.DataTypeLength > 0)
    {
        parameter.Size = columnInfo.DataTypeLength;
    }

    this.Provisioning.Tables[columnInfo.TableName].FilterParameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the error is self-explanatory.

the FilterParameters can only be set if the scope inherits from a filter template. you cannot set the FilterParameters for a normal scope, only FilterClause.

Using parameter-based filters is a two step process: Defining the filter/scope template and creating a scope based on a template.

I suggest you re-read the blog entry again and jump to the section Parameter-based Filters.

Comment: I think I found what I was missing. I somehow missed the `SqlSyncScopeProvisioningType.Template` in the constructor for the provisioning object. Thanks for your help.